# While loop doesn't end even when element is not enabled/displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, webdriver

While loop should end when element `makePaymentButton` is not enabled/displayed but it does not.

> Error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == makePaymentButton

```
while(driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).isEnabled())
{
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(9000);
}
```

Comment: Instead of while loop, you can wait for the visibility of element using web driver wait.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to what is wrong with this and why this loop wouldn;t end

Comment: If you are getting exception then your loop will end right?

Comment: Instead of is enabled. You can try with is displayed. Because sometimes is enabled is always true.

Comment: @Murthi. Tried with isDisplayed() too. Its not working

Comment: are you getting the exception on the condition of the while loop or inside the while loop

Comment: @Grasshopper : 
When Statements inside while loop are success, my web page reloads and this button 
driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).
is not displayed anymore.
So When while loop condition is checked again, it throws an exception

Comment: The issue is that there is a quirk with methods like isEnabled(), isDisplayed() that it returns true when element is enabled or displayed. But when it is the opposite it throws an exception instead of returning false. Write a method which wraps this call and catch the exception and return false in catch block. Refer to this for more details and solution - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cause you are trying to find a element who t's not displayed anymore. You will need to put the findelement code in to a "try".

Must be something like this:

```
WebElement verificator = driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).isEnabled()
while(verificator)
          {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
         try {
           driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
           Thread.sleep(4000);
           driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).click();
           Thread.sleep(9000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           verificator = false;
        } 

     }
```

This is a pseudo-code. If it not work, pls verify de sintax

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you chose a while loop, but the same thing can be accomplished without one. In the following example, an [Explicit Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) is used.

```
// Define and wait (up to 10 seconds) for the "Make Payment" button
WebElement btnMakePayment = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("makePaymentButton")));
// Fill out password
driver.findElement(By.name("password_ccCvv")).sendKeys("999");
// Click "Make Payment" button
driver.findElement(By.id("makePaymentButton")).click();
```

Comment: I am using while loop, because after entering values in the textbox, i am unable to move forward, where as in 3rd or 4th attempt during the while loop I am able to move forward